# Gulp BrowserSync and npm start

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'd like to start my NodeJS application using BrowserSync but it seems not working.

Error message : Error: listen EADDRINUSE

**Edit #1:**

I found this way to resolve my issue.

```js
gulp.task('sync', ['start', 'watch'], function(cb) {
    browserSync.init({
        files: ['**/*'],
        proxy: 'http://localhost:3000',
        port: 4000
    });
});

gulp.task('start', function() {
    var called = false;
    return nodemon({
        script: './bin/www',
        watch: ['Application.js']
    }).on('start', function onStart() {
        if (!called) {
            cb();
        }
        called = true;
    }).on('restart', function onRestart() {
        setTimeout(function reload() {
            browserSync.reload({
                stream: false
            });
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"! And please find a more meaningful title to your question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EADDRINUSE` means that the port number which `listen()` tries to bind the server to is already in use. So, in your case, there must be running a server on port 80 already. If you have another webserver running on this port you will get the `EADDRINUSE` error.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function () {
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function() {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        proxy: "http://localhost:5000",
        files: ["**/*.*"],
        browser: "google chrome",
        port: 7000,
    });
});

gulp.task('nodemon', function (cb) {
    nodemon({
      script: './bin/www/app.js'
    })
    .on('start', function () {
      cb();
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
     // Make sure failure causes gulp to exit
     throw err;
   });
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Can you try to change the  `port: 8080` to some other port that you are sure is it not in use already,  something like `8097`

Comment: It doesn't work too... The BrowserSync server is well started but not the NodeJS application... And I'd like to start both of them on the same port.

Comment: The only way to do that is by using the browserSync proxy setting. I have updated the example so you can try. (Remember to change the paths to match your app)

Comment: Works better but `Error: task completion callback called too many times`

Comment: The `gulp.task('nodemon', function (cb)` was taking a callback and returning an stream (`return nodemon({...`) at the same time. I think that is the `callback called too many times` issue. Please give it a go and lt me know if you still have problems.

Comment: See edit #1. I found something to resolve my issue ;)

Comment: In my case, a docker container was taking port 3000, the default one, stopping that container did the trick.